# Tooltips in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to implement tooltips similar to how this would be achieved in an Angular Material app, but this isnt working in an Angular Dart sample application. I am trying:

```
<button mat-raised-button
    tooltip="test"
    title="test 123"
    matTooltip="By default, I delay"
    aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip that has custom delays 
    through a default config">
  Button with delay-default tooltip
</button>
```

I've also tried:

```
  <p>Use the [trailing] content selector to add a tooltip.</p>
  <material-input label="With a tooltip">
    <material-icon
        trailing
        tooltipTarget
        size="medium"
        icon="help_outline"
        #tooltipRef="tooltipTarget">
    </material-icon>
  </material-input>
  <material-tooltip-card [for]="tooltipRef">
    This is a paper tooltip!
  </material-tooltip-card>
```

Going from this as a source ( https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_tooltip ) , I have also tried

```
<button materialTooltip="abc">test</button>
```

None have worked. How do I go about showing simple tooltips on hover?

Comment: Did you add these providers https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/fecf215d65a19be97fd248036640e297161c49e3/example/material_tooltip_example/lib/material_tooltip_example.dart#L37-L40 ?

Comment: No I had included the directives but not the providers. That fixed it, if you answer i can mark as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you registered the required providers

```
  providers: [
    popupBindings,
    tooltip.materialTooltipBindings,
  ],
```

like it's done in

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/fecf215d65a19be97fd248036640e297161c49e3/example/material_tooltip_example/lib/material_tooltip_example.dart#L37-L40

Registering them once in the AppComponent should do for the whole app.

Comment: I have the same problem, I followed the example and checked several times, but the tool tip is still not showing. I'm either blind or dumb (or both).
I have a material icon in one of my components
'''<material-icon [icon]="holiday.recurring ? 'repeat' : 'looks_one'"[materialTooltip]="holiday.recurring ? 'Recurring holiday' : 'Single date holiday'"></material-icon>'''
I have '''providers: [popupBindings,tooltip.materialTooltipBindings,],'''
and all needed Tooltip directives as in example code. Is there anything else to check. I tried to put providets to top level component, it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas.

Comment: After loosing few hours trying to find out the problem, I solved it. By debuging I ended at browser/feature_detector#supportsHover() which returns false in Google Chrome (74.0.3729.131, Linux). I opened the app in Firefox and tooltips work as they should. OMG, thank you Google for this :-(